# How to sync an app with Drive files by command?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm using Drive REST API to create/edit app files on Google Drive, using DriveServiceHelper from https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples.git example.
When I try to query, I get a list of almost all the files I've ever created on the app, although I have already deleted them manually on Drive.
Now, I understand the info I get on a 'query' may contain cached information, but the app requires a real-time list.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if those files have been deleted from the Trash/Bin because the list API also returns deleted files that haven't been removed from the Bin.

Comment: Yeah, took me some time to get to that. I don't see any difference though between those deletes and those in use. Is there any difference in the metadata of the file?